# Runtime error in code: Preorder to Postorder in tree

Tags: python, data-structures, runtime-error, binary-search-tree

I have written a simple code in python for given preorder of a tree to Postorder traversal of tree in a Binary Search Tree. In my compiler everything is working fine but while uploading it to the online compiler it is showing:

Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 31, in 
    preorder_to_postorder(arr, n, 0)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 24, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(right, len(right), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 21, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 21, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 21, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 21, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3c8565281b5fa09fe07720.py", line 21, in preorder_to_postorder
    preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
  File "/home/6cc826a55a3.................

Here is the link of the question https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/preorder-to-postorder/0
When I compile and test the code, it works fine but when i submit the code it shows the above error in same fashion, the way i have posted above.
Please help

Here is my code:

```
def preorder_to_postorder(arr, n, counter):
    left = []
    right = []
    temp = arr.pop(0)
    parent.append(temp)
    if len(arr) == 1:
        while counter > 0:
            arr.append(parent.pop())
            counter -= 1
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            print(arr[j], end=" ")

    for i in range(0, n-1):
        if arr[i] < temp:
            left.append(arr[i])
        else:
            right.append(arr[i])

    if len(left) > 1:
        counter += 1
        preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
    if len(right) > 1:
        counter += 1
        preorder_to_postorder(right, len(right), counter)

t = int(input())
parent = []
for k in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    preorder_to_postorder(arr, n, 0)
    print()
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error traceback?

Comment: @SwaggaTing This is the full error which i have posted here. The dots at end are there in the compiler only.

Answer (score 0):

So there is some problem in logic of your code when

1. N=1 
   you will pop from arr, it's size will become 0 and you have no check for that
2. There is a special condition when your code is failing
   when N=3, arr=[2,1,3] kind of input
   ideally it should print 1,3,2 but check what your code is printing.

I don't know why you made this so complicated using counter and parent variable while you can write something simple Like This

```
def preorder_to_postorder(arr, n, counter):
    left=[]
    right=[]
    for i in range(1,n):
        if arr[i] < arr[0]:
            left.append(arr[i])
        else:
            right.append(arr[i])

    if len(left) > 0:
        preorder_to_postorder(left, len(left), counter)
    if len(right) > 0:
        preorder_to_postorder(right, len(right), counter)
    print(arr[0],end=' ')

t = int(input())
parent = []
for k in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    preorder_to_postorder(arr, n, 0)
    print()
```

Try corner cases always while solving problems.